# Can I customize the display text for my website URL in my developer story?

Tags: support, developer-story, hyperlinks

I'd like to add some [UTM parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters) the web site link I have in my Developer story. However, I'd prefer to keep the *display* of the web site clean. Do we have the ability to change the underlying URL while still making the display name look clean?

I'd like to do something like this, but when I do, it appears the square brackets get stripped and the entire thing is smashed together:

```
[http://www.example.com](http://www.example.com/?utm_campaign=fall-2016-job-hunt&utm_medium=dev-story-link&utm_source=stackoverflow)
```

This would display `http://www.example.com`, as it currently does, but allow me to pass UTM parameters so that I can see, on my side, where I'm being most effective in getting potential employers to look at my information.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?